# Download empty string as empty string (not null) from Snowflake to Databricks

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks

I would like to load the data from Snowflake table into the Databricks pyspark cluster. In order to do it I ran:

```
a = spark.read \
    .format("snowflake") \
    .options(**cfg['sf_connection_options']) \
    .option("dbtable", <db.schema.table>)\
    .load()
```

Unfortunately if the string is empty it is downloaded and treated as Null.
Is there any way to properly treat: Nulls as Nulls and empty string just as empty strings?

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide your schema manually , assume below are the columns in your table/DF

```
custom_schema = StructType([ 
StructField("Year", IntegerType(),True),
StructField("Month", IntegerType(),True), 
StructField("DayofMonth",IntegerType(),True), 
StructField("DayOfWeek", IntegerType(),True), 
StructField("DepTime", IntegerType(),True), 
StructField("CRSDepTime", IntegerType(),True)])
```

So , instead of this

> .option("dbtable", <db.schema.table>)\

use

```
.schema(customSchema)
```

Should be like ---

```
a = spark.read \
    .format("snowflake") \
    .schema(customSchema)
    .options(**cfg['sf_connection_options']) \
    .load()
```